# Tomcat logs explained

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have Tomcat installed on windows. In the Tomcat log directory I have various logs:

```
catalina
localhost
manager
host-manager
commons-daemon
localhost_access_log
tomcat8-stderr
tomcat8-stdout
```

I have been trying to find out where each one of those logs coming from and where it gets configured. Nothing useful in Tomcat documentation.

I know that `logging.properties` deals with `catalina, localhost, manager, and host-manager` but the rest - I have no clue. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localhost_access_log is configured via the access log valve. Look in `server.xml` for the relevant `<Valve>` element.

The remaining three (commons-daemon, tomcat8-stderr and tomcat8-stdout) are all generated by the Tomcat Service wrapper. This is just a renamed Commons Daemon executable. The docs for that should have more info but the basics are as follows:

- commons-daemon - The service wrappers own log file
- tomcat8-stderr - redirected output from stand error for the service wrapper process
- tomcat8-stdout - redirected standard out for the service wrapper process

Comment: thank you! Is there any way to rotate them? All other logs I was able to rotate using Log4j but not these

Answer (score -1):

You need to route stderr and stdout by enabling swallowOutput="true" in context.xml

```
<Context override="true" swallowOutput="true">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```